# How to change input value when it set triggered using event 'invalid'

Tags: javascript

i want to send message to specific contact in whatsapp web.
before send message i must select contact from input box.
i'm start with this code

```
document.getElementsByClassName("input-search")[0].value="my Contact Name";
```

text changed, but contact not filtered.

this is the html code:

```
<input class="input-search" data-tab="2" dir="auto" title="Search or start new chat" value="" type="text">
```

[This image show it will change with invalid event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGuw1.png)

Comment: If it's a native invalid event, they might be setting hidden fields. Otherwise, its a custom implementation. I'd suggest you inspect the element to see what events are being listened for, then dispatch them as a user would (e.g. clicks, keypresses, blur event)

Comment: this is the commmand from invalid event:

function(e, t) {
  if (h._enabled) {
    var n = o.getPooled(e, t);
    try {
      f.batchedUpdates(i, n)
    } finally {
      o.release(n)
    }
  }
}